# How to assign Role to User in has_many :through relationship through console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 2 models **User** and **Role**, and has_many :through relationship between them

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many    :user_roles,             
  has_many    :roles,  through: :user_roles
end
```

and

```
class Role < ApplicationRecord
  has_many    :user_roles, 
  has_many    :users, :through => :user_roles
end
```

and relate model

```
class UserRole < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :role
end
```

The question is how to assign role to specific User through console. I tried with

```
>User.last.roles = [:admin] (Role which I want to assign has name: admin and role_id: 1)
```

but I get an error

> ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch (Role(#47275896707120) expected, got :admin which is an instance of Symbol(#47275846312980))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an instance of role:

```
User.last.roles << Role.find_by(name: :admin)
```

You also want to use the `<<` (shovel) operator to add to the association and not the setter which will replace it.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass an instance of Role:

```
admin_role = Role.find(...)
User.last.roles = [admin_role]
```